# How can you create a CSS3 gradient in Opera?

Tags: css, opera, gradient

I can create CSS gradients in IE6/7/8/9/FF3.6+ and Chrome (see below).

My question is:

**How would one create a gradient in Opera?**

```
.gradient{
        /*Mozilla Firefox 3.6*/
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dcdcdc, #c6c6c6);

        /*Webkit aka Google Chrome*/
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #c6c6c6),color-stop(1, #dcdcdc));

        /*Internet Explorer 6,7 and 8*/
        filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dcdcdc', endColorstr='#c6c6c6');

        /*Internet Explorer 8 only*/
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dcdcdc', endColorstr='#c6c6c6')";

        /* Opera */
        /* ??? */
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this one:

`background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg,rgb(18,79,126),rgb(59,137,197));`

Comment: note that the -o- prefix is no longer needed in Opera 12.1 and above.

Answer (score 13):

Opera 10.x supports SVG in background images, and SVG lets you do gradients in much the same way Firefox and Safari’s CSS extensions do.

Opera’s SVG background support seems to have some nasty bugs when your element also has borders in 10.0 and below, but as of 10.5 it seems reasonably solid (in my limited experience).

**CSS**

```
/* Opera */
background-image: url(gradient.svg);
```

**gradient.svg**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: #c6c6c6;"/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #dcdcdc;"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <rect x="0" y="0" fill="url(#gradient)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

You can also include the SVG directly in the CSS file, using a data url, if you url encode the SVG. (In e.g. Python, you can do this by removing newlines and unnecessary spaces, and then passing the file’s contents to `urllib.quote`).

It’s a bit unreadable, but it saves an HTTP request, and if you’ve got more than one SVG gradient embedded in your CSS file, you should see some bandwidth savings over individual files (assuming your CSS file is gzipped).

```
/* Opera */
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20version%3D%221.0%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient%20id%3D%22gradient%22%20x1%3D%220%22%20y1%3D%220%22%20x2%3D%220%22%20y2%3D%22100%25%22%3E%3Cstop%20offset%3D%220%25%22%20style%3D%22stop-color%3A%20%23c6c6c6%3B%22/%3E%3Cstop%20offset%3D%22100%25%22%20style%3D%22stop-color%3A%20%23dcdcdc%3B%22/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Crect%20x%3D%220%22%20y%3D%220%22%20fill%3D%22url%28%23gradient%29%22%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%20/%3E%3C/svg%3E);
```

Answer (score 10):

Should be the same as Mozilla's, but with the Opera identifier:

```
-o-linear-gradient(top, #dcdcdc, #c6c6c6);
```

Works in Opera 11.10 and newer.

Answer (score 9):

On Dev.Opera has been published article how to use linear gradients on Opera (11.10+).
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-linear-gradients/

Answer (score 5):

CSS3 Gradients, using the latest syntax (closer but not exactly the same as Firefox, as the spec has evolved) are in development now in Opera Presto (our rendering engine). It likely wont make it for Opera 11, but will probably make it for the version after.

Answer (score 5):

Latest Opera builds (>=2042) supports CSS3 linear-gradient.

Answer (score 4):

Opera [does not support](http://groups.google.com/group/opera.general/browse_thread/thread/c46891ac05e5392e/e4fbb2fc57d7e89e?pli=1) CSS3 gradients (yet). You can somehow emulate them using [box-shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/), though. See http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/beautiful-ui-styling-with-css3-text-shadow-box-shadow-and-border-radius/.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of this?

Comment: @etoxin: there’s quite a lot of examples in the article linked in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For Opera Browser

```
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(0,189,0),rgb(0,181,255));
```

Answer (score 1):

> -o-linear-gradient(top, #dcdcdc, #c6c6c6);

That is by far the best option. I tried the SVG method and not only does it look awful in the code but it also ends up causing the background to dissapear in firefox.

Thanks everyone for posting. I had to recently implement gradients in Opera as well and it was a pain.