# Do CSS Gradients work in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, gradient, internet-explorer-9

Unfortunatly i don't have a machine that I can test IE9 on yet (still in XP) and browsershots still doesn't do IE9 yet. Could someone tell me if IE9 supports css gradients? Here is a page which has gradients applied. Does it work?

http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css3-dropdown-menu/css-gradient-dropdown.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not.

See here: http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient

It will support SVG as a background though, which is currently used to make gradients for Opera.

Comment: ok, so it doesn't work, but how do we use SVG on an element in HTML? SVG is completely new to me.

Comment: @David: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084614/how-can-you-create-a-css3-gradient-in-opera

Comment: Note that Opera supports linear gradients since v11.10: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-linear-gradients/

Answer (score 3):

IE9 currently lacks CSS3 gradient support. However, here is a nice workaround solution using PHP to return an SVG (vertical linear) gradient instead, which allows us to keep our design in our stylesheets.

```
<?

header('Content-type: image/svg+xml; charset=utf-8');
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>
';

$from_stop = isset($_GET['from']) ? $_GET['from'] : '000000';
$to_stop = isset($_GET['to']) ? $_GET['to'] : '000000';

?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#<?=$from_stop?>" stop-opacity="1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#<?=$to_stop?>" stop-opacity="1"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: url(#linear-gradient);"/>
</svg>
```

Simply upload it to your server and call the URL like so:

```
gradient.php?from=f00&to=00f
```

This can be used in conjunction with your CSS3 gradients like this:

```
.my-color {
    background-color: #f00;
    background-image: url(gradient.php?from=f00&to=00f);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f00), to(#00f));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f00, #00f);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f00, #00f);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f00, #00f);
}
```

If you need to target below IE9, you can still use the old proprietary 'filter' method:

```
.ie7 .my-color, .ie8 .my-color {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr="#ff0000", endColorStr="#0000ff");
}
```

Of course you can amend the PHP code to add more stops on the gradient, or make it more sophisticated (radial gradients, transparency etc.) but this is great for those simple (vertical) linear gradients.

Comment: Thanks neave... here my .NET version:

[http://blog.marcovalsecchi.it/2011/03/ie9-css3-gradient-support-net.html][1]


  [1]: http://blog.marcovalsecchi.it/2011/03/ie9-css3-gradient-support-net.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/06/ies_big_leap_fo.html), IE9 does not support gradients.

Answer (score 1):

**IE9 does not support CSS gradients.**

Look at the bottom of [**this comparison between Firefox 4 and IE9**](http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/ie9/ie9_vs_fx4.html).