# Crossbrowser background-image repeat-y gradient

Tags: html, css

I have image `1*910px` high, I want to make background.

here is my css:

```
body
{
    background-image:url('/Content/themes/start/images/bgw.png');
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: #e8f3fb;    
    color: #000;
}
```

If I have page with long content it looks good, but if page does not have long content the background doesn't display correctly.

I did try to set `min-height`, but it is not what I want to achieve.

Maybe there is some other way of doing this, or if not: how may I fix it?

Is there any way to make background more dynamic according to the content size?

Any advice/sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a CSS gradient, they’re reasonably well-supported now.

E.g.

#### Fallback for older browsers

```
background: #333 url(gradient.gif) left top repeat-x;
```

#### Firefox, Safari/Chrome, and [apparently Opera 11.10 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084614/how-can-you-create-a-css3-gradient-in-opera/5336797#5336797)

(Some earlier Operas support [SVG in background images, which is another alternative for gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084614/how-can-you-create-a-css3-gradient-in-opera/5336797#5336797), but I’m not sure how well it plays with the other methods. Plus you have to learn some SVG.)

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #333 0%,
    #555 100%
);
background: -o-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #333 0%,
    #555 100%
);
background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0%,#333),
    color-stop(100%,#555)
);
```

#### IE

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
    startColorstr='#333333',
    endColorstr='#555555',
    GradientType=0
);
```

Comment: @Reg: if Opera users complain about the lack of a gradient background, just buy them both a drink to make up for it.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite I would prefer to go with background: #333 url(gradient.gif) left top repeat-x; What is the better height for gradient.gif to have?

Comment: @Reg: the same height as your content, I guess?

Comment: +1 for amusing Opera comment. It's a shame it doesn't have more market share, it's a good browser.

Comment: @thirtydot: indeed, and it’s good to have a third good rendering engine out there. I’m delighted (and somewhat amazed) it’s still around for those who use it. I wouldn’t lose much sleep over nice visual effects being missing from it though.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite I have dynamic content Anyway i need to use background-color to auto fill the rest of the background if content is too big, but what is the height for gradient.gif you would suggest or it is doesn't matter?

Comment: @Reg: Just to rephrase your question: you’re saying you don’t know how tall your content is, and you’re asking me how tall your gradient background image should be so that it works with your content?

Comment: @Reg: just re-read your question. If your `background-color` matches the colour at the top of your gradient image, then you’re correct to position it at the bottom of its element (i.e. `50% 100%`). But if your `background-color` matches the bottom of your gradient image, then you should position it at the top (i.e. `50% 0`). If you do this, it should look reasonable whatever height it is.