# css3 gradient not work in opera

Tags: css

i want to use css 3 gradient in all browser for a specefic element.  i use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor for that and it create the following code :

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 );
```

it works fine on all major browsers Except Opara.
what is Problem and solution? i am using Opera 11.0

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-gradients

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your css maybe there is a problem somewhere else...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you create a CSS3 gradient in Opera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084614/how-can-you-create-a-css3-gradient-in-opera)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is Opera 11.0 solution is Opera 11.1

http://caniuse.com/css-gradients

Answer (score 1):

Opera11 is not CSS gradient featured.

Answer (score 1):

Safari 4+, Chrome 1+, Firefox 3.6+, and Opera 11.10+ are now supporting CSS3 gradients.
Go here for more details: [www.css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you..

```
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg,rgb(18,79,126),rgb(59,137,197));
```